# Trouble implementing a recursive call in C

Tags: c, recursion, roman-numerals

So I'm I've been working with C for the very first time, and I think I'm having trouble using recursion. For instance, to return a value for a recursive call in C#, I might use `return methodRecursiveCall(parameter)`. In C, I have this statement, which is a part of a roman numeral converter:

```
int convert(char *s)
{    
    int val = 0;
    int index = 0;
    int length = strlen(s);

    while (length >1)
    {

        if (s[index] == 'I')
        {
            if(s[index + 1] == 'V' || s[index + 1] == 'X' || s[index + 1] == 'C' || s[index + 1] == 'D' || s[index + 1] == 'M')
            {
                val--;
                index++;
                length--;
                convert(&(s[index]));
            }
            else
            {
                val++;
                index++;
                length--;
                convert(&(s[index]));
            }
        }

        if (s[index] == 'V')
        {
            if(s[index + 1] == 'X' || s[index + 1] == 'C' || s[index + 1] == 'D' || s[index + 1] == 'M')
            {
                val = val - 5;
                index++;
                length--;
                convert(&(s[index]));
            }
            else
            {
                val = val + 5;
                index++;
                length--;
                convert(&(s[index]));
            }
        }

        if (s[index] == 'X')
        {
            if(s[index + 1] == 'C' || s[index + 1] == 'D' || s[index + 1] == 'M')
            {
                val = val - 10;
                index++;
                length--;
                convert(&(s[index]));
            }
            else
            {
                val = val + 10;
                index++;
                length--;
                convert(&(s[index]));
            }
        }

        if (s[index] == 'C')
        {
            if((s[index + 1]) == 'D' || (s[index + 1]) == 'M')
            {
                val = val - 100;
                index++;
                length--;
                convert(&(s[index]));
            }
            else
            {
                val = val + 100;
                index++;
                length--;
                convert(&(s[index]));
            }
        }

        if (s[index] == 'D')
        {
            if(s[index + 1] == 'M')
            {
                val = val - 500;
                index++;
                length--;
                convert(&(s[index]));
            }
            else
            {
                val = val + 500;
                index++;
                length--;
                convert(&(s[index]));
            }
        }

        if (s[index] == 'M')
        {

            val = val + 500;
            index++;
            length--;
            convert(&(s[index]));

        }    
    }
    return val;
}
```

My question specifically is about the `convert(&(s[index]));`, which is meant to be a recursive call. It is meant to convert an entire Roman numeral to decimal, however it only converts the first character. That is normally where I would put a 'return'. I'm not sure how to pull this off in C, however.

Comment: I can't see any point in using recursion here. Your function is given a `char*` pointer as an argument. Why not just step through and process the input string with a single loop (e.g., `while (*s) { ... }`). Also, try using a `switch` statement instead of all the `if` constructions.

Comment: You seem to have forgotten about `L`, aka 50.

Comment: You can do it the same way as in C#. `return convert(&(s[index]));` Have you tried that, and does it work like you expect? I haven't checked for logic errors or anything, but that's all there is to returning a value. Have you tried the algorithm successfully in C#?

Comment: There's nothing fancy about recursion in C.  You've already discovered the `return` keyword.  It's the recursion logic of these function that is the problem.  A while loop with recursion inside of it seems very strange.  And you never use the returned value after calling `convert`.

Comment: You are calling `convert` and ignoring the return value. Why are you calling it? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: the while loop will defeat the purpose of the recursion and result in an incorrect final value.  instead, use the same condition in the while statement to exit the bottom of the recursion stack.   Also, use the if/then/else/endif structure so repeated checks of the same byte of the string are not checked over and over.  Suggest using a switch statement for the checking of what the current byte under test value is, to make the decision of what to do next.   There is a logic error, as an example, this value 'IX' is not handled correctly.

Answer (score 0):

For this fragment from near the end:

```
if (s[index] == 'M')
{
    val = val + 500;
    index++;
    length--;
    convert(&(s[index]));
}
```

You probably want something like:

```
if (s[index] == 'M')
    val = 1000 + convert(&s[index+1]);
```

You know that the `M` maps to 1,000; the total value will be 1000 + the value of what follows the `M`, which is what the expression states.  Note that the parentheses around `s[index+1]` are not necessary.

You'll need to make similar changes throughout the code.  You also need to review why you have iteration mixed in with recursion; you should use one or the other.

Note that your code doesn't seem to cover `L` aka 50.

Personally, I think this is not the best way to do the conversion.  All else apart, it will be hard to spot that `MXMC` is invalid.  My code uses an array of structures containing a string and the corresponding value (`M` and `1000`; `CM` and 900) etc, and once one of the values has been used up (`CM` can only be used once; `M` can be used multiple times; `CD` can be used once; `C` can be used multiple times — that's coded too), then it can't appear again later.  And it uses iteration rather than recursion.

---

Here's a moderately simple adaptation and fix to your code.  It works OK for converting 'known to be valid' Roman numbers; it doesn't work well for validating them.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int convert(const char *s);
int convert(const char *s)
{
    int val = 0;
    int i = 0;

    if (s[i] == '\0')
        return 0;

    if (s[i] == 'I')
    {
        if (s[i + 1] != 'I' && s[i + 1] != '\0')
            val = convert(&s[i + 1]) - 1;
        else
            val = 1 + convert(&s[i + 1]);
    }

    if (s[i] == 'V')
        val = 5 + convert(&s[i + 1]);

    if (s[i] == 'X')
    {
        if (s[i + 1] == 'L' || s[i + 1] == 'C' || s[i + 1] == 'D' || s[i + 1] == 'M')
            val = convert(&s[i + 1]) - 10;
        else
            val = 10 + convert(&s[i + 1]);
    }

    if (s[i] == 'L')
        val = 50 + convert(&s[i + 1]);

    if (s[i] == 'C')
    {
        if ((s[i + 1]) == 'D' || (s[i + 1]) == 'M')
            val = convert(&s[i + 1]) - 100;
        else
            val = 100 + convert(&s[i + 1]);
    }

    if (s[i] == 'D')
        val = 500 + convert(&s[i + 1]);

    if (s[i] == 'M')
        val = 1000 + convert(&s[i + 1]);

    return val;
}

int main(void)
{
    const struct roman
    {
        const char *str;
        int num;
    } test[] =
    {
        { "I",                  1 },
        { "II",                 2 },
        { "III",                3 },
        { "IV",                 4 },
        { "V",                  5 },
        { "VI",                 6 },
        { "VII",                7 },
        { "VIII",               8 },
        { "VIIII",              9 },
        { "IX",                 9 },
        { "X",                 10 },
        { "XI",                11 },
        { "XII",               12 },
        { "XIII",              13 },
        { "XIV",               14 },
        { "XV",                15 },
        { "XVI",               16 },
        { "XVII",              17 },
        { "XVIII",             18 },
        { "XIX",               19 },
        { "XVIIII",            19 },
        { "XX",                20 },
        { "XXI",               21 },
        { "XXX",               30 },
        { "XL",                40 },
        { "L",                 50 },
        { "LXXVIII",           78 },
        { "XCVIII",            98 },
        { "IC",                99 },
        { "XCIX",              99 },
        { "C",                100 },
        { "D",                500 },
        { "M",               1000 },
        { "MMMDCCCLXXXVIII", 3888 },
        { "MDCMMCCLXIIIIII", 3666 }, // Not good for validating!
    };
    enum { NUM_TEST = sizeof(test) / sizeof(test[0]) };

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_TEST; i++)
    {
        int value = convert(test[i].str);
        printf("%s  %15s = %4d vs %4d\n", (value == test[i].num) ? "== PASS ==" : "!! FAIL !!",
               test[i].str, value, test[i].num);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
== PASS ==                I =    1 vs    1
== PASS ==               II =    2 vs    2
== PASS ==              III =    3 vs    3
== PASS ==               IV =    4 vs    4
== PASS ==                V =    5 vs    5
== PASS ==               VI =    6 vs    6
== PASS ==              VII =    7 vs    7
== PASS ==             VIII =    8 vs    8
== PASS ==            VIIII =    9 vs    9
== PASS ==               IX =    9 vs    9
== PASS ==                X =   10 vs   10
== PASS ==               XI =   11 vs   11
== PASS ==              XII =   12 vs   12
== PASS ==             XIII =   13 vs   13
== PASS ==              XIV =   14 vs   14
== PASS ==               XV =   15 vs   15
== PASS ==              XVI =   16 vs   16
== PASS ==             XVII =   17 vs   17
== PASS ==            XVIII =   18 vs   18
== PASS ==              XIX =   19 vs   19
== PASS ==           XVIIII =   19 vs   19
== PASS ==               XX =   20 vs   20
== PASS ==              XXI =   21 vs   21
== PASS ==              XXX =   30 vs   30
== PASS ==               XL =   40 vs   40
== PASS ==                L =   50 vs   50
== PASS ==          LXXVIII =   78 vs   78
== PASS ==           XCVIII =   98 vs   98
== PASS ==               IC =   99 vs   99
== PASS ==             XCIX =   99 vs   99
== PASS ==                C =  100 vs  100
== PASS ==                D =  500 vs  500
== PASS ==                M = 1000 vs 1000
== PASS ==  MMMDCCCLXXXVIII = 3888 vs 3888
== PASS ==  MDCMMCCLXIIIIII = 3666 vs 3666
```

Note that the last 'number' is horribly bogus (1000 + 500 + 900 + 1000 + 100 + 100 + 50 + 10 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1).