# Roman numbers to letters

Tags: c, roman-numerals, letters-and-numbers

How can I translate or process a roman number to a decimal number in words and vice versa? I want to do this in C. The idea is to get the number or the letters and process it.

Here is an example:

```
MDXXIII = One thousand five hundred and twenty-three
One thousand five hundred and twenty-one = MDXXI
```

Comment: This is still unclear, do you want to change the roman numerals to decimals **numbers** or **decimal number as word strings**?

Comment: See [Trouble implementing a recursive call in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28219838/trouble-implementing-a-recursive-call-in-c/) which is, despite its title, about converting a number in Roman numerals to decimal/binary.  Recursion is not necessary; iteration is fine.  ("To iterate is human; to recurse, divine", but the Romans were human, not divine.)

Comment: Note that converting an integer into words is a separate problem from converting an integer to roman numerals; the converse is also true.  The conversion from roman numerals to integer requires error checking in a way that the formatting does not.  The same applies (in spades ♠︎, redoubled) to converting words into a integer.  You need 4 separate converters, therefore.

Comment: This topic has been [covered before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9073150/converting-roman-numerals-to-decimal) although Java was used there.

Answer (score 2):

From decimal to roman is quite simple; the other way around is a bit more tricky.

There are several sets of rules for roman numerals; let's take the most common one:

- the signs for the multiples of five and ten are

  - `I` one
  - `V` five
  - `X` ten
  - `L` fifty
  - `C` one hundred
  - `D` five hundred
  - `M` one thousand
- values in between can be done by concatenation of multiples of the same character

  - `II` two
  - `III` three
  - `XX` twenty
  - `XXX` thirty
- values in between can be done by concatenation of multiples of different characters

  - `VI` six
  - `IV` four
  - `XI` eleven
  - `DI` fifty one
  - `CX` one hundred and ten
  - `XC` ninety
- some combinations are forbidden, better: only the following combinations are allowed

  - `ab` if `a >= b` (e.g.: `II`, `VI`)
  - `ba` if `5b = a` or `10b = a` (e.g.: `IV`, `XD`, `IX`, `XC`)
- exceptions:

  - sometimes the maximal number of concatenated symbols of the same value is three (e.g.: `III` and `IV`, `XXX` and `XD`) or four (e.g.: `IIII` instead of `IV` and `XXXX` instead of `XD`) but never more or less.

Hint: the conversion of one base to another base is best done from the smallest to the largest part of the number.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do this is by reading the entire roman number string and then processing the strings from the back.

> Eg: **XIV you start with V, = 5 move back 1,** now it's I, **I is less than
>   V so now subtract off 1, which is 4.** Then you move back to X, and now
>   X is greater than I, so add 10 to the earlier value (which was 4),
>   which then becomes **`4+10 = 14.`**

**Step 1:** Start
**Step 2:** read the roman numerical as string
**Step 3:** find length of the roman numerical
**Step 4:** for each character in the string

```
 1. if(char = I) then decimal = 1
 2. if(char = V) then decimal = 5    
 3. if(char = X) then decimal = 10  
 4. if(char = L) then decimal = 50  
 5. if(char = C) then decimal = 100  
 6. if(char = D) then decimal = 500  
 7. if(char = M) then decimal = 1000  
 8. otherwise invalid character
```

**Step 5:** repeat step 4 until the length of the string
**Step 6:** k = char[length - 1]
**Step 7:** for each character of decimal string

1. **`if(decimal[i] > decimal[i - 1]) then k = k - decimal[i - 1]`**
2. **`else if(decimal[i] = decimal[i - 1 or decimal[i] < decimal[i - 1)   then k = k + decimall[i - 1]`**

**Step 8:** repeat **step 7** until the length of decimal string
**Step 9:** print decimal value
**Step 10:** Stop

Comment: This code does not compile.  That makes it tricky to validate that it works properly — I'm suspicious of the algorithm described as it doesn't match the one I use. I tried to fix the code, but my fixed version doesn't convert 'ix' (or 'IX') — I'd like to know whether your fixed version does.  I also got the result -9 from converting 'XI'; again, I'm willing to accept that I didn't guess the correct fix, but it's crucial that you provide working code. (These aren't even the torture-tests I had in mind — they're basic counting, except I started with 9 instead of 1. Actually, 'I' causes trouble.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Thanks for checking it, I have updated my answer and added a generic algorithm instead.

Comment: I've removed my down-vote, but I'm not yet convinced by the algorithm (but neither have I yet worked out where it is wrong).  My suspicion is that it doesn't do sufficient validation (so it might interpret IXMMCLDIIX or similar nonsense).